# android.view.WindowInsets ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

`android.view.WindowInsets` is added in API level 20.

I import `android.view.WindowInsets` in my `CustomLayout` and override `onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets)`, but `ClassNotFoundException` occurs in some phones, whose api level are from 14 to 21. What is the reason?

Occurred on:
Rooted Nexus 5, Android 4.4.2

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/WindowInsets
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug.java:900)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:855)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:793)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:416)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.executeCommand(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
   at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.WindowInsets" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/***-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/***-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
   at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug
```

Comment: If WindowInsets requires minimum API level 20 then how can it be found on API level 14 to 19?

Comment: It occurs only in some phones, the other phones(API level 14 to 21) we test are just ok. How to explain it?

Comment: There's no need to explain. If Android added a function in API level 20 you should not be running that on API level lower than 20.

Comment: I understand what you said,but the function I override is called by the system. API level lower than 20 system would never call it. What I confused is that it occurs even on api level 20~21, but not on all api level lower than 20.

Answer (score 7):

## What happens

The system traverses all public methods of a view and encounters the overridden `onApplyWindowInsets` with `WindowInsets` parameter. This type does not exist in the system hence the crash.

Lollipop introduced the `View.onApplyWindowInsets` method but it also introduced the `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener`, which if set, is invoked instead of the aforementioned method.

## When does it happen

I've had reports of this on Samsung devices running Android 4.4.

It can be triggered by dumping view hierarchy.

## What to do about it

So far this doesn't solve anything. To the rescue comes support-v4 library:

```
public class SampleView extends View {
    public SampleView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SampleView(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SampleView(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this, new android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(final View v, final WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                // Do whatever you needed to do in the first place...
                return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Use the above in your common constructor. `WindowInsetsCompat` is provided by the support-v4 library so it's always present, it does not expose any non-existent future classes directly on the view, and the code is effective only since Lollipop (where actual `WindowInsets` were introduced).

## Why is this happening

Beats me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `android.view.WindowInsets` in lower API versions if it was added in API level 20.

Comment: It occurs only in some phones, the other phones(API level 14 to 21) we test are just ok. How to explain it?

Answer (score 0):

i meet this too because i use Viewpager2

in viewpager2 use windoeinsets but only use @RequiresApi, it make compile pass , but runtime fail.

i downgrade viewpager2 from beta-01 to stable 1.0.0 so i fix this