# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/Icon on Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582430/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-graphics-drawable-icon) problem reported for android. Suggested solution is to Androd Support library version 27 but I am using xamarin and I can only see support library 26.1.0.1 until today and I am using it already. Is xamarin way behind Google? how can we resolve this error on xamarin.android

Exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/Icon
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.getExportedPropertyMethods(ViewDebug.java:960)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.exportMethods(ViewDebug.java:1047)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:997)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewProperties(ViewDebug.java:983)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpView(ViewDebug.java:900)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:870)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dumpViewHierarchy(ViewDebug.java:867)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dump(ViewDebug.java:793)
       at android.view.ViewDebug.dispatchCommand(ViewDebug.java:416)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.executeCommand(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
       at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:65)
       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Support library v27 requires bindings to Android 8.1 which are not yet available in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: @JonDouglas yes i saw this entry after creating this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113340/incompatible-api-level-since-upgrade-to-oreo-8-1